# PHP action logout alternative URL fix

Tags: php, content-management-system, anchor, admin

I have created a PHP password protected site with log-in page. I am using the following link for logging out.

```
<a href="admin.php?action=logout"?>Log out</a>
```

The problem is it redirects back to the index.php, but instead of showing my URL as EXAMPLE.com it shows my URL as EXAMPLE.com/index.php, which is undesirable. How can I accomplish a log-out and go back to the clean, desired url.

Comment: <a href="admin.php?action=logout">Log out</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logout page you just add this redirect at the end of code

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com/");
```

This will redirect to the same index page with url *example.com*, but not show */index* in url

Don't add

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com/index");
```

It will show *example.com/index* in url

Answer (score 2):

After logout redirect using the following command:

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com/login.php");
```

You can also do it by javascript in client side by using:

```
window.location='http://example.com/login.php'
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali MasudianPour, I used the PHP command and it certainly does the job. I am considering JS/jQuery options now, as I am attempting an AJAX solution. Can that JS function trigger an AJAX script?

Comment: If you want to do this by ajax, you can echo an output such as echo "OK" and echo "FAILED" in php. Then, in client side you can check the result and write a code to check if result was OK so window.redirect='url' and if not do something else